# Match two dates without seconds and show result

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

What I'm trying to accomplish is showing correct result.
What I have is two different tables, `orders` and `orders_products`.

I'm trying to match the `orders.order_date` and `orders_products.order_date` between each other and exclude the seconds because there is delay between the databases and the information won't show.

**orders_products** example.

```
id  user_id user_name quantity product price order_date
19  12  Test    1   Advanced game overlay       20     2015-02-17 19:31:16
20  12  Test    1   Advanced standby overlay    20     2015-02-17 19:31:16
21  12  Test    1   Description images          15     2015-02-17 19:31:16
```

**orders** example.

```
id user_id user_name user_twitch user_email specific_color specific style webcam_size monitor_resolution faster_delivery order_message order_date user_ip order_status order_paid
4   12  Test    John Doe    Test    Test@hotmail.com    Blue    random information  1024x768    0   ... 2015-02-17 19:31:14 xx.xx.xx.xx 1   0
```

If you compare the `order_date` between those two tables the `orders.order_date` is 2 seconds slower and the information won't show.

I'm trying to show a "Your orders" page, and SUM() the total of each order and it's products listed.

```
$sth = $conn->prepare(
    "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y %m %d %H:%i') AS date_convert "
    . "FROM users, orders "
    . "WHERE users.user_id = :user_id AND orders.user_id = :user_id"
);
$date = date('Y:m:d H:i', strtotime($result['order_date']));

$sth = $conn->prepare(
    "SELECT SUM(price) AS price_sum "
    . "FROM orders_products "
    . "WHERE user_id = :user_id AND order_date = :order_date"
);
$sth->bindValue(':user_id', $row['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':order_date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: You have an `orders` table and an `orders_products` table and you do not have an `OrderId` connecting them?  You need to fix your data.

Comment: I agree with Gordon.  And here is a way the code should have been written...  `SELECT @ts := NOW(); INSERT INTO ... (...@ts ...); INSERT (...@ts ...).  That way, the two INSERTs have the same time.

Comment: Even better than my previous comment is that you _should_ have created an id for the `orders`, then included that id in the corresponding rows of `orders_products`.  Then `JOIN` on them -- no comparing of times needed!  And no ambiguity if someone manages to place two orders in the same second.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the date portions and ignore the times (and fix your date format):

```
// Use Y-m-d as that is the format MySQL is expecting
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result['order_date']);
// Use DATE() to only use the date poprtion of the datetime value
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) AS price_sum FROM orders_products WHERE user_id = :user_id AND DATE(order_date) = :order_date");
$sth->bindValue(':user_id', $row['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindValue(':order_date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```